# Darkmode mode on tailwind css not working

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, darkmode

I have added the dark mode classes to tailwind CSS but it is not working
I tried giving `class="dark"` for my `html`  `<html class="dark">` document manually but it is not working.

My `config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
   content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
   theme: {darkMode:"class",extend:{},},
   plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a mistake when including the dark mode class the darkmode should be child of `modeule.export`
`module.exports = {`
`darkMode: "class",`
`extend: {},`
`},`
`plugins: [],`
`};`